# Update MUI datepicker format label

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, dayjs

I have an MUI Datepicker using dateAdapter Dayjs. Which I would like to change the format label to **DD/MM/AAAA**.

Setting the **LocalizationProvider** with location **pt_BR** displays "DD/MM/YYYY"

[image: field]

Is there a way of not changing the date format but displaying **DD/MM/AAAA** instead of **DD/MM/YYYY** when the user clicks on the field to set the date manually?

Answer (score 1):

I solved that using the **localeText** from the **LocalizationProvider** setting **fieldYearPlaceholder** as 'AAAA'